# Arrangements, Visual basic, excel

Tags: excel, vba

An instructor has a class of 25 students. Each student is identified by a number from 1 to 25. All tests are stored in a two-dimensional array, with each column containing the grades for each test. The instructor would like to enter the student number and the test number and have the grade for that test printed on the monitor. Develop a solution to output the needed information.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim StudentVolume(1 To 25, 2 To 5) As Single
    Dim StudentID As Integer, Grade As String, TestNumber As Integer

    For StudentID = 1 To 25     'outer loop start'
        For TestNumber = 1 To 5 'inner loop start'
            StudentVolume(StudentID, TestNumber) = InputBox("Enter Student Volume")

            If Grade >= 100 And Grade <= 90 Then
                Grade = A
            Else
                If Grade >= 89 And Grade <= 80 Then
                    Grade = B
                Else
                    If Grade >= 79 And Grade <= 70 Then
                        Grade = C
                    Else
                        If Grade >= 69 And Grade <= 60 Then
                            Grade = D
                        Else
                            If Grade >= 59 And Grade <= 0 Then
                                Grade = F
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Cells(StudentID, Grade) = StudentVolume(StudentID, Grade)

        Next TestNumber 'inner loop end'
    Next StudentID      'outer loop end'

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this homework or something?

Comment: If you double/triple/quadruple-space your lines it's very difficult to view your code...

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are not Homework solution providers or other code writing service.  Looking at the code provided you need to be aware of the four key practises for novice VBA programmers

1. Always, always, always put Option Explicit at the start of each Class/Form/Module.
2. Use F1 to get help.  In the VBA IDE put your cursor on a VBA or Office object and press F1.  The MS help page for that item will load.  Make sure you read and understand the help page.
3. Compile your code before you try to Run it.  In the VBA IDE use Debug.Compile Project
4. Install the fantastic free Rubberduck addin for VBA.  In particular, pay attention to the code inspections, they are a great learning resource for VBA and the Office applications.